# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)

Tags: python, json, django, rest

So my goal is to find a name of a country using its ISO Alpha-2 country code. I figured this would be a good time to try out a RESTful API (the [World Bank API](https://datahelpdesk.worldbank.org/knowledgebase/articles/898590-api-country-queries) to be exact) for the first time. I started to use [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/api-integration-in-python/) in trying to achieve my goal and it seems like `requests.get()` is the answer to my problem, I tried it out and got this:

```
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import requests
>>> resp = requests.get('http://api.worldbank.org/countries/br')
>>> resp
<Response [200]>
>>> resp.json()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 866, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 315, in loads
    s, 0)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I'm not really sure what went wrong or what it's telling me to do (I'm not that familiar with JSON). Any explanations to this and how to fix it?

I am using:

Windows 7 64-bit

Python 3.5.1

Django 1.10

`requests` package 2.13.0

Comment: Are you sure that the `GET` request you send returns a response in json?

Comment: FWIW, using a BOM in UTF-8 is not recommended by the Unicode Standard , but a lot of Windows software insists on it. :( See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8 for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The response you get from that endpoint is not a JSON.
Hence it cannot be parsed as a JSON even using `json.loads()`.

It returns an XML which has to be parsed differently.

You could use:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree 

resp = requests.get('http://api.worldbank.org/countries/br')
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(resp.content)
print( root.find("{http://www.worldbank.org}country")[1].text )
```

To learn how to properly parse XML data you should read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).